# How to merge/combine HTML table cell without colspan

Tags: html, merge, cell, html-table

I need to merge the center cells in an HTML table, but `<td colspan="3" rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>` not work as expected. The below image shows what happens when I use `colspan` and `rowspan` - it messes up the table.

[image]

How should I merge 9 cells like the above image without using `colspan`. I really want to combine table cells so they don't expand.  Can I do it using HTML or do I need to use a jQuery solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`colspan` is the right thing to do.  The problem you're having is that you added more columns than you intended.  Every time you use a `colspan` of more than 1, you need to knock a corresponding number of `<td>` tags off that row.  Also, remember that using `rowspan` effectively adds a `<td>` to every row that the span covers.  So when you do a `colspan="3" rowspan="3"` then you need to knock 2 cells off the row that contains the spanned cell, and three off the next *two* rows.

In the case of your 10x10 table with the 3x3 hole in it, you need this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***EDIT***

I'm feeling generous and bored, so here's some PHP.  You can tweak the spansize and cellMax values and everything should continue working.  Rough edges though.  I haven't tested every possible way to break it.

```
<?php
function draw_table_with_hole($rows, $cols, $span_start_row, $span_start_col, $span_rows, $span_cols) {
    $spanning = 0;
    for ($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++) {
        if (--$spanning > 0) {
            $cell = $span_cols;
        } else {
            $cell = 0;
        }
        echo "<tr>";
        for (; $cell < $cols; $cell++) {
            $cell_code = "<td>&nbsp;</td>";

            if ($row === $span_start_row && $cell === $span_start_col) {
                $cell_code = '<td colspan="' . $span_cols . '" rowspan="' . $span_rows . '.">&nbsp;</td>';
                $cell += ($span_cols - 1);
                $spanning = $span_rows;
            }

            echo $cell_code;
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
?>
<table>
     <?php draw_table_with_hole(10, 10, 3, 4, 3, 3); ?>
</table>
```

Comment: seems good solution but I'm printing the 10*10 table inside `for` loops. so this solution like impossible. any idea..?

Comment: I assume that there's an outer loop printing rows, and an inner loop printing cells?  In that case, you'll have to adjust the loop counter for the inner loop after printing a spanned column, and then adjust it back when you've run out of rowspan.

Comment: Thanks for this it works fine but if we have different `rowspan` and `colspan` size ex: colspan 2and row span 3 above `php` code make error.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to change it to track the row spanning and column spanning independently.

Comment: Yah I tried that but in inner loop you have used `cell` value for iteration. So How could I use different value?

Comment: See updated code.  That should give you something to work from, but that's your last freebie ;)